# Persistent change of caption width in memoir

Tags: captions, memoir, width

How do you persistently change caption width in `memoir`? I know you can use `\changecaptionwidth` followed by a  `\captionwidth{...}`, but that only works within a float and I don't want to have to specify that all the time.

Also, if caption widths can be set persistently, how do you revert to using the full width when using subcaptions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least for me, `\changecaptionwidth` *does* work in the document preamble.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
    adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
    adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.}

\changecaptionwidth
\captionwidth{0.6\textwidth}

\setfloatadjustment{figure}{\centering}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{\sometext}
\end{figure}

\normalcaptionwidth

\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{\sometext}
\end{figure}

\changecaptionwidth

\begin{figure}
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{\sometext}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Huh. Now that I retry it, it works for me too; before I got a compilation error. Must have been after I fixed the `memoir`-`caption` conflicts after removing the `subfig` package.

Comment: If you face an error, always try to delete auxiliary files and then compile again.